# MySQL how to migrate to new server without data lost?

Tags: mysql, migration, amazon-rds, master-slave-replication

I'm using [AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/), with 1 master & 1 slave.

Just now I alter 1 of the table and hangup halfway, so I force stop the process. Now the database got some problem.

Let say I wanted to instantiate a new RDS instance and migrate the whole DB over *(around 1TB++)*, how can I fully migrate, because every seconds got new data comes in.

The problem now is because if want to copy the DB over, estimated around 30 minutes. What about the data in this 30 minutes during the migration?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Take the slave offline and clone it.

Replication will be backed up, and will catch up after bring brought back online.